# How to get the source code of a project from launchpad

Tags: launchpad, source-code, open-source

How to get the source code of a project from launchpad

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can install [bzr](http://packages.ubuntu.com/bzr)

```
sudo apt-get install bzr
```

and then you can download any branch you want, for example: `bzr branch lp:inkscape` in any directory you want